Cookies not being set in browser
I'm making a simple express.js aplication, it has a login form that sends a request, and if authenticated redirects to a page in the frontend and attaches a JWT token to the website's cookies. The JWT token is being generated, the user is being redirected, but no token is being set.
Here's the server.js:
app.use(cookieParser());

const allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:5501', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500']; // Live server ports

app.use(cors({
    origin: allowedOrigins,
    credentials: true // Permite envio de cookies e outras credenciais
}));

dotenv.config()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

Here's the login route:
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('\n\n\n-----------------------/LOGIN/--------------------------');
    const { login, senha } = req.body;

    try {
        const users = ler_dbJSON();
        const conta = users.filter(user => user.senha === senha && user.login === login);

        if (conta.length > 0) {
            const contaVerificada = conta[0]
            const secret = process.env.SECRET;
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: contaVerificada.id }, secret, { expiresIn: "7d" });

            console.log("Token: ", token)
            res.cookie("token", token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                secure: true
            });

            const responseUrl = contaVerificada.adm === true ? "page1.html" : `pages2.html`;
            console.log('-----------------------/LOGIN/--------------------------\n\n\n');
            return res.status(200).json({ url: responseUrl });

        } else {
            return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Login ou senha incorretos." });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: "Ocorreu um erro ao carregar o banco de dados", erro: err.message });
    }
});

Finaly, the request in the front end
axios.post(api_url, {
        login: login,
        senha: senha
    }, { withCredentials: true }

I've used postman to test the route, it's working perfectly. In the frontend it's parcially working, i'm being redirected as expected to the correct pages, but no cookies are present (tested it by inspecting the page, and using console.log(), both showed a page with no cookies.)

console.log can't show httpOnly cookies, or cookies from a different origin - not even sure what you expect to see when inspecting the page - do you mean the application or storage tab in developer tools?

You might take a look at the response, on Firefox inspect > Network, and at the storage within Storage, to see your cookies

Nothing appears in both the "Application" tab and the "Storage" tab, the cookie that was supposed to be there simply doesn't appear. It was working a while ago, but I believe I deleted it manually to do a test, and it hasn't appeared there since. And also when it was there in the "application" tab it was not accessible in GET requests (when trying to log the req.cookies i got an empty array)
